# Does "unique visitors" in Google Analytics mean "number of different people"?

Tags: google-analytics, statistics, visitors, session

My website's Google Analytics shows me 100,000 unique visitors for a time period of 12 full months.  Does that means that these are actually 100,000 different people that visited my website in a year?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, unfortunately it's not literally 100,000 different people. More accurately, it's 100,000 different cookie values. A user can visit your site for the very first time and be counted with a first unique visit, but if they clear their cookies, or log in from a different computer, or do private browsing, then a subsequent visit would be "unique" again. So technically, they have generated two unique visits, but it's the same person.

Comment: Furthermore, all separate devices count. If a user visits your site with PC, tablet and phone, he is three visitors.